# How to import a class from a c++ dll to vb.net

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, import

I have written a dll where I define a class with several functions and members.
I import c++ functions from a dll to vb.net before, but never a whole class.
To import functions I used before this construction:
in c++

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall  sum(int a, int b, int &c) {
    c=a+b;
}
```

and in vb.net I used this:

```
<DllImport("TestingDLL.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Shared Sub Sum(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double, ByRef c As Double)
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to import a class with its members and functions?

Thanks in advance!